# why I don't see my page layout in all page layout when editing a page

Tags: sharepoint-designer, office-365, site

I have created a page layout from `Site Setting -> Design Manager -> Edit Page Layout -> Create New Page Layout`

Its conversion was successful but I can't find an option to do the followings:

- Add a new page with this new page layout
- Change the page layout of an existing page to this newly created page layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the page, approve, then publish as a major version.

Comment: thnx for your quick response. It really helped me a lot. One more question here. How can I place multiple `page content` fields so I can edit them from Web Interface...? I tried copy pasting snippet from gallery but content in both fields are same (from second field)

Comment: Sorry, I need to check.

Comment: For testing purposes, I have created two columns (in a table row) in the Layout. Now I want to put different text in both fields. I'd place `page content` field twice but as I said the content is same. Please help me I m new in sharepoint

Comment: view source and check what is in common between the two page content fields.

Comment: These two fields in Page Layout source are completely identical. No change

Comment: let me know how you are assigning the value. I mean the code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11194/discussion-between-harsh-and-biju-joseph)